# postgres case expression with a where clause

Tags: postgresql, case

I want to filer data from my postgres database. i want to use where clause together with postgres case expressions for filtering data in a single query. i want some thing like this logic

```
select *from [my-table-name] where ( CASE 
     WHEN column1 = 0 THEN condition1 
     ELSE condition2
  END
)
```

what i want is if my column1 is zero i want to filter those rows with condition1 and if column1 is not zero i want to filter those rows with  condition2. if case expression was not used i have to write query like this

```
select *from [my-table-name] where column1 = 0 and condition1
select *from [my-table-name] where column1 <> 0 and condition2
```

for getting those required data

i tried writing seperate queries for getting those required data

Comment: Hm, `WHERE column1 = 0 and condtion1 or column1 <> 0 and condition2`? Why do you need `CASE` instead of plain boolean logic? Are `condition1` or `condition2` computationally heavy? Anyway, here's the documentation link to working syntax: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL

Comment: Also, you always have `UNION` to merge two queries into one, it may be more efficient in some circumstances compared to heavy `CASE` in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your first query looks working ! You get any errors ?

Comment: no condition1 and condition2 was not computationally heavy. but if those column values are zero my filtering condition will become  different. because i was filtering a date column on certain conditions. but on seeing your second comment about union, i think it will be a better solution. thanks for the help

Comment: @SelVazi i got this query from stackoverflow, i didnt use it because it contained @ tag in some places, i trimmed certain parts for explaining that logic. upon your recommendation i will check it when i get some free time and i will update the information

Comment: The second query block can be optimized with an `OR` Operator. `select *from [my-table-name] where (column1 = 0 and condition1) or  (column1 <> 0 and condition2)`

Comment: `(column1 = 0 AND condition1) OR (column1 <> 0 AND condition2)` is not equivalent to `(CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN condition1 ELSE condition2 END` because the `CASE` statement will return the value of `condition2` when `column1 IS NULL` but the pure logical expression will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CASE` expressions in `WHERE` clauses can adversely affect query performance because doing so can prevent the execution planner from identifying opportunities to use available indexes. I'll use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` to demonstrate the potential performance difference between using `CASE` expressions and pure conditional logic in the `WHERE` clause.

The following commands establish the demonstration environment:

```
CREATE TABLE case_tests (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  column1 integer);

INSERT INTO case_tests (column1)
SELECT random() * 2
  FROM generate_series(1,1000000) s(n);
```

The first query uses `CASE` to determine which additional conditional test is applied:

```
SELECT *
  FROM case_tests
  WHERE CASE column1
          WHEN 0 THEN id <= 100
          ELSE id > 999900
        END;
```

Running this query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` returned the following:

```
Seq Scan on case_tests  (cost=0.00..21925.00 rows=500000 width=8) (actual time=0.014..87.607 rows=99 loops=1)
  Filter: CASE column1 WHEN 0 THEN (id <= 100) ELSE (id > 999900) END
  Rows Removed by Filter: 999901
Planning Time: 0.050 ms
Execution Time: 87.631 ms
```

The second query is functionally equivalent to the first, but uses pure conditional logic instead of a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
  FROM case_tests
  WHERE    (column1 = 0 AND id <= 100)
        OR (column1 = 0 IS NOT TRUE AND id > 999900);
```

The resulting explain plan shows a total execution time about 1000 times faster than the query using `CASE` (0.088 ms vs. 87.631 ms):

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on case_tests  (cost=10.38..665.39 rows=95 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.051 rows=99 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((id <= 100) OR (id > 999900))
  Filter: (((column1 = 0) AND (id <= 100)) OR (((column1 = 0) IS NOT TRUE) AND (id > 999900)))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 101
  Heap Blocks: exact=2
  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=10.38..10.38 rows=197 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on case_tests_pkey  (cost=0.00..5.22 rows=106 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=100 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id <= 100)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on case_tests_pkey  (cost=0.00..5.11 rows=91 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=100 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id > 999900)
Planning Time: 0.145 ms
Execution Time: 0.088 ms
```